# R when sampling letters (LETTERS) how do I check if the next letter is a greater letter value then the previous one?

Tags: r

I need to keep printing (drawing) letters until the next letter is out of order from the previous one.

An example would C-D-E-A,  the amount of draws would be 4 since A is not after E.  I am attempting the use of a while loop to do this.

```
draw <- function() {

   drawletters <-  sample(LETTERS)
   drawnum <- 0


   while (drawletters > drawletters) {
      firstdraw <- drawletters
      drawletters <- sample(LETTERS)
      drawnum <- drawnum + 1
    }

   print(drawletters)

}
```

I understand how my conditional statement is wrong in my loop, but I do not know the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one potential solution:

```
# Create an empty (NULL) vector to store the results of each run
results <- c()

# Create the function
draw <- function(){
  # Start with draw_num = 0
  draw_num <- 0
  # Draw a letter
  firstdraw <- sample(LETTERS, 1)
  # Add 1 to draw_num
  draw_num <- draw_num + 1
  # Draw another letter
  nextdraw <- sample(LETTERS, 1)
  # Add another 1 to draw_num
  draw_num <- draw_num + 1
  # Print the letters (you can omit this if you don't need it)
  print(firstdraw)
  print(nextdraw)
  # Then use a while loop to print the letters and add 1 to draw_num
  # until the next letter comes before the previous
    while(nextdraw > firstdraw) {
      firstdraw <- nextdraw
      nextdraw <- sample(LETTERS, size = 1)
      draw_num <- draw_num + 1
      print(nextdraw)
    }
  # Then print draw_num
  print(draw_num)
  # And append draw_num to the results vector
  results <<- c(results, draw_num)
}

# Run the function a bunch of times (e.g. run "draw()" 10X)
draw()


# Then you can see the average number of letters drawn across all runs
mean(results)
#>[1] 2.7
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I am looking for exactly, though it kinda helps.  The main goal is to stick with one sample with no replacements.  I was told that the answer was roughly around 2.72 draws.  I guess the main thing is how can I compare the sample to itself .  I assume we use brackets `[]` but I dont know the correct way to do so